# centos7 as NFS client only

Tags: centos, nfs

I want make sure a CentOS7 machine can only be an NFS client and not an NFS server, if possible.

When I type `mount` I see-

```
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw,relatime)
```

`showmount -e` reveals:

```
clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Unable to receive: errno 111 (Connection refused)
```

…so, I'm not sure if an NFS server is running or not.

`chkconfig --list` and `systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled` also don't indicate an NFS server is running.

Comment: Have you enabled rpcbind and have you started it ? yum install nfs-utils yum install rpcbind systemctl enable nfs-server rpcbind ; systemctl start nfs-server rpcbind rpcinfo -p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ps -ef | grep rpc
```

A NFS server would be running processes such as `rpc.nfsd`, `rpc.mountd`, `rpc.lockd`, `rpc.statd`.

Also:

```
cat /etc/exports
```

This shows the list of filesystems to be exported from a NFS server.

```
cat /var/lib/nfs/xtab
```

This shows the list of exported filesystems.

```
cat /proc/fs/nfs/exports
```

This prints the kernel export table for NFS.

If all the above commands report nothing, you don't have a NFS server running.

Comment: `ps -ef | grep rpc` shows **rpciod** and `cat /proc/fs/nfs/exports` shows two commented lines, **# Version 1.1** and **# Path Client(Flags) # IPs**.  Would statd and lockd be running for an NFSv4 server?

Comment: `rpciod`, `statd`, and `lockd` are used by NFS clients. If there's no trace of the `nfsd` daemon and  the two text files are empty, then you aren't running any NFS server.